# GANTT in JasperReports / IReport

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I´m using actual IReport Prof. 4.1.2.3

I am trying to built a GANTT Chart.

1)

How can i put values in, (or near by)  the GANTT Bars like this ? :
   ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*___**...

|       0:23:47         |                 |   00:09:31   |                    |       02:33:11                            |

---------------------------------------------------------------------------...

2)

How can i configure that only **X** Categories can be shown in the Categorie Axis ?
If i let work the diagramm Engine for me, i will have some small lines, but the bars has to be much thicker.

And that happens, if i only have 4 values in the Categories Axis.

3) regarding to 2):

Is there a function / parameter , that configures the bar Height from the GANTT ?

thx and Best regards

Christian

Answer (score 0):

i hope this answer your question I'm using Gantt Chart in IReport, 
you must input the value to build automatic the chart that required that is series expression, task expression(like task) start(date/time), end(date/time) the percentage you can ignore you can see example pic in my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11097696/manipulate-gantt-with-ireport)