# Manipulate Time range of Gantt chart with iReport

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport, jfreechart

I'm trying to develop a Gantt chart in *iReport*, but the time range is displayed in months. 
I want it to be in date or week.

Is this possible in *iReport*?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Customizing Dates on the Gantt Chart for Jasper Reports](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7770045/customizing-dates-on-the-gantt-chart-for-jasper-reports)

Answer (score 2):

I'm unfamiliar with [ireport](/questions/tagged/ireport), but you may be able to use the approach shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7771293/230513) by specifying `DateTickUnitType.DAY` and the desired interval. A related example may be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11010228/230513).

Comment: Sorry, no experience with `jrxml`. Is `ChartCustomizer` available to you?

Answer (score 0):

You can extend page width and the chart width to accommodate shorter ranges. The intervals automatically adjust to available page width.